# Move CSS from vf page to external file

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, class, css

I have the following method implemented in my controller class:

```
public String buildTemplate(Task task) {

    Id taskId = task.Id;

    List<Task_History__c> listTaskHistory = [SELECT Field1, Id, Field2, Username__c, LastModifiedDate FROM Task_History__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :taskId];
    String pageHTMLContent = '<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>table.css_class , .css_class th, .css_class td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; } table.css_class th { text-align: center; } </STYLE></HEAD><BODY><TABLE class="css_class">';
    pageHTMLContent += '<TR><TH>Comment1</TH><TH>Comment2/TH><TH>Last Modified By</TH><TH>Last Modified Date</TH>';

    for(Task_History__c taskHistory :listTaskHistory) {
        String oldValue = taskHistory.Old_Value__c;
        String newValue = taskActivityHistory.New_Value__c;
        String userName = taskActivityHistory.Username__c;
        DateTime lastModifiedByDate = taskActivityHistory.LastModifiedDate;
        pageHTMLContent += '<TR>';
        pageHTMLContent += '<TD>' + oldValue + '</TD><TD>' + newValue + '</TD><TD>' + userName + '</TD><TD>' + lastModifiedByDate + '</TD>';
        pageHTMLContent += '</TR>';
    }

    pageHTMLContent += '</TABLE></BODY></HTML>';

    return pageHTMLContent;
}
```

I'd like to move the css "*String pageHTMLContent = 'table.css_class , .css_class th, .css_class td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; } table.css_class th { text-align: center; } ';*" part in the Visual Force page

```
<apex:page standardController="task" extensions="TaskHistoryController">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

or to an external file?

Could you please give an example how the css would look when implemented in vf page or an external file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Trailhead [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_static_resources) on Visualforce has, about halfway down the page, an example of how to declare an `<apex:styleSheet>`:

```
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!
      URLFOR($Resource.jQueryMobile,'jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css')}"/>
```

You would replace the references to jQuery with the name of the Static Resource that you've uploaded (as a ZIP file), and the path to your CSS file within the Static Resource.

More details are to be found in the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm).